# Streaming of data in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

Can any one detail and resolve issue in streaming of Data in R. the following code consist of package installed with stream, streamMOA, ff, devtools. i am getting Zero micro clusters and zero Macro cluster which is shown. can any one guide me?

```
k <- read.table("three hours from 11am 16_08_2016_data.txt",col.names=c("H", "T"))
myffdf <- as.ffdf(k) 
myffdf <- myffdf[c("H","T")] 
mydatastream <- DSD_FFDFstream(x = myffdf, k = 100, loop=TRUE) 
mydatastream 
FF Data Stream 
Class: DSD_FFDFstream, DSD_R, DSD 
With 100 clusters in 2 dimensions Contains 5400 data points - currently at position 1 - loop is TRUE 

#### Cluster (first part) > myclusteringmodel <- DSC_CluStream(k = 10) 
myclusteringmodel 
CluStream + k-Means (weighted) 
Class: DSC_TwoStage, DSC_Macro, DSC Number of micro-clusters: 0 Number of macro-clusters: 0 

kmeans <- DSC_Kmeans(3) > recluster(kmeans, myclusteringmodel) 
myclusteringmodel 

CluStream + k-Means (weighted) 
Class: DSC_TwoStage, DSC_Macro, DSC Number of micro-clusters: 0 Number of macro-clusters: 0
```

Comment: note: micro and macro clusters are zero

Comment: This seems to me like a programming question, so it is better suited on stackoverflow. Also, as a tip: try expanding on what you tried in solving this problem. What do you want this code to do? Are the intermediate values in this code what you expect them to be? Can you find a smaller code example that shows the problem?

Comment: stream <- DSD_ReadCSV("test.csv",header = TRUE,sep=",") 
clustream <- DSC_CluStream(m=50)
update(clustream, stream, 500)

Comment: previous one is the code and following is the error from update           Error in .jcall("StreamMOA", "V", "update", object$javaObj,.jarray(as.matrix(d),  :

Comment: Ok, this is much better. 3 lines of code and an error messages. Could you add this to your original question? And is this the whole error message you got? Did it specify anything about what kind of error it was?

Comment: Thank you for the response.No i cant add these two codes, since both are reading files differently in R. first code is reading file using read.table(). Second code is reading using DSD_ReadCSV. Though action of work from both are same but cant add it up. In my fist code my issues are with zero micro cluster and zero macro cluster. In my second code my error is in update  of clustream. Please brief me.

Comment: In Short i have issues with streaming of dataset in R. i am not getting results. i have tried with clustream and streaming k means under streamMOA package. The package is not properly supporting other datasets for streaming and getting these issues

Comment: Can you run the R code of the examples without errors? in file streamMOA/doc/streamMOA.Rnw? run `browseVignettes()`; search for streamMOA; click "R code" ; copy it, run it. Should generate lots of plots?

Comment: @ knb Thank's for your reply.                                                      I'm able to get output for example code with (DSD_BarsAndGaussians) data. But when i try to run with iris dataset I'm facing issue as mentioned earlier.